# Typing generics based on optional argument in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic function `foo()` that has an optional argument `fn` that could be a function for transforming the return value. If `fn` is not provided, simply use `string`. For example

```js
const foo = <T>(fn?: (data: string) => T) => {
  const data = "some data"
  if (!fn) {
    return String(data)
  }
  
  return fn(data)
}
```

I had a hard time to let generics infer the return value correctly. If `fn` is not provided, the return value should be inferred as `string`. And if it is, the return value should be inferred as whatever the return type of `fn` is.

Currently, if I call `foo()`, the return type is `unknown`. If I provide a `fn`, the return type is always inferred as `string | (return type of fn)`, in which case `string` should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, there is workaround in TS to achieve your goal using `conditional types` and `function overloads`. By using function overloads, you can define different return types based on whether the fn parameter is provided or not.

```js
type ReturnOrTransform<T> = T extends ((data: string) => any) ? ReturnType<T> : string;

function foo<T extends ((data: string) => any)>(fn: T): ReturnOrTransform<T>;
function foo<T extends undefined>(fn?: T): string;
function foo<T extends ((data: string) => any) | undefined>(fn?: T): ReturnOrTransform<T> | string {
  const data = "some data";
  if (!fn) {
    return String(data) as ReturnOrTransform<T> | string;
  }
  return fn(data);
}

const result1 = foo(); // type of result1 is string

const transformFn = (data: string) => ({ length: data.length });
const result2 = foo(transformFn); // The inferred type of result2 is { length: number }
```

you can play with it [there](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7A8kgKkghigzgGYD2SAtgDyYB8UAvFJlBAB7AQoAm%20UAFL5xzAcALij5gSAJYoA5gEp6tPCEUB%20WPGQpM4CFVpiJ0uQG4AsACgrhBCgDGwKcRRQSxKszYdufAUNFxSRkFJSgVeWpeQhQxTHkxOERUDGw8IlJKGgtLWwcnFzdiDyZWdi4eO04IQhkITiiYtTiEoJNZHLzHZ1d3TzKfHn5BYSNguUU6ZRRVKAAfKCqauobolGbGVqTtVNwCEnIDebaQqABvKygoexcJKBGceigAInxiMmgH55yrqUI%20ACEMUUF0sVyuSC0qCgAGVxrJ-MJFDgeNsUlg9hlDjRjsYQj8oABfS5QSHJXooRE4eQ5YnWSw3AjAUkQfAIAA2wAAjE93LwaVArFZGXdJOkDmQAGKuBhUsbtSa0XhnKDsjiyYAACzEDwAdGq5FqiTThbdmZC2ZyAEy84q8MX7TLSgVWIA)

Comment: Thank you, did not know we can use overloads this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [default value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-parameter-defaultsmepMYEA) for your generic `T` like `T = string` in your case. When a argument is passed to your function `foo`s return type will be of type `T`. If `foo` is called without any argument the default value of `T` will be the return type, which is `string`.

```
const foo = <T = string>(fn?: (data: string) => T) => {
  const data = "some data";
  if (!fn) {
    return String(data) as T;
  }
  
  return fn(data);
};

const result1 = foo();  // Inferred as string
const result2 = foo(_ => 5);  // Inferred as number
const result3 = foo(_ => false);  // Inferred as boolean
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVFNoCcCWYA5gHwAUcYA-AFwxkAmAhlE3XoUQJQokwY9kfAN4BYAFAwYoSLGatsAIgggAtgFMY8pooDcEqfjj0AhJR5jJUmLnVQArrjAwAylALFGLJjyYR++lYAvgYwobYOTvBgXqxcgUGBEjLQNuoQ9gA2UACM2AggZPFSAPQlMACSYHDquLYMMH447pzJ4Km2GdkATPmIZAD6vDAAzDwwZZXVtfWN-mD2qgBGtW2yaV1QI32FQ0LwTJkQ6sUT5VU1deoNTUuImepMYEA)

Comment: Thank you, default type and `as T` are what I misssed